# Trouble retrieving data from kivy's jsonstore

Tags: python, kivy, jsonstore

I'm having issues retrieving data from a '.json' file if the key contains non-ascii characters.
To explain better i want to illustrate this issue with an example.
Say if i want to save data into a json file as follows

```
store = JsonStore('example.json')
store.put('André Rose', type = 'sparkling wine', comment = 'favourite')
```

Then I want to retrieve it as follows

```
store.get('André Rose')
```

this returns an error that says:

> KeyError: 'Andr\xc3\xa9'

I believe the problem is the non-ascii character " é ".
so my question is how can I save stuffs like this into a json file, and retrieve without getting this key error?

Comment: Perhaps we aren't being careful enough with string encoding when stored. This might be worth raising as an issue on the kivy github page, it could be a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I just opened a github account and raised d issue. Hopefully I'll get a response soon

Comment: @ inclement pls as a work around for me, is there a way to retrict input to kivy's TextInput so that only ascii characters can be entered. Please a sample code will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

"There is a bug in kivy 1.8.0 under Python 3. When you are using Kivy 1.8.0 and Python 3, URlRequest fails to convert the incoming data to JSON. If you are using this combination you'll need to add:" (Philips, Creating Apps in Kivy)

```
import json 

data = json.loads(data.decode())
```

I'm not sure if this will help your particular problem, but I thought I might throw it out there.